# Why is my subview on top of my UItextView not getting touches?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITextView with scrolling disabled and a long-press gesture recognizer. When I long-press my custom UIImageView shows up but it does not start handling touch events. Instead all touch events go to the textView below.

I tried to add the custom UIImageView to the view controller and the UITextView, but it does not get the touches in both cases.

Has anyone encountered the problem or knows how to fix it?

Comment: is the [`userInteractionEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-SW13) property of your `UIImageView` set to `YES` ?

Comment: THANK YOU! it was enabled but for some reason I had to reenable it in the long press action method.

Answer (score 0):

How are you presenting the UIImageView? I think we'll need to know more about your view hierarchy to answer this. However, you might check that your UIImageView has userInteractionEnabled set to YES, as it's defaulted to NO.

Also, is the long-press gesture recognizer installed on the image view, or the text view?